# Is it possible to tell if one activation function is better than the other one based on their graphs?

Tags: neural-network, activation-function

I am attempting to formulate my own activation function. However, I'm new to neural networks, am not yet ready to test it, but would want to know if I already landed on a better activation function than my benchmark before pushing through for a successful study.

These are their graphs. Mine is in green and the benchmark is in purple.[image]

Is it possible to tell which one is better based on these graphs?

Thanks!

Comment: Both functions are smooth, non-monotonic, and bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr No.

The choice of an activation function is highly dependent on the task at hand, so there isn't necessarily a "better" in the general sense, let alone a signal you could get from a chart.

The chart also doesn't tell you if the activation or its derivative is easy/inexpensive to compute relative to the other, which can be a consideration.